# SXA search Facets for field

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I want to make the facet using that PropertyDetailsBeds (No Bedrooms) field inside the "Property Details" so that I can use that facet in the Search filter.

[image: bedroom fields]

What needs to be done in order to use that in the Facets? Has anyone done something similar to that?

Comment: Did you check in solr schema, if that custom field is getting index?  Ideally it should get index by default. Then go to /sitecore/content/HBCS/IntranetHub/Settings/Facets path and create a new facet utilizing that custom field.

Comment: Is your PropertyDetailsBeds a custom field? As your screenshot shows a section "Property Details" and 3 fields..  so I'm not sure what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: @Gatogordo yes I want to make the facet using that PropertyDetailsBeds (No Bedrooms) field inside the "Property Details"

Answer (score 0):

To use a facet, you need a field in the index. This can be a computed field as well.

As we don't have details about your custom field the steps you should take are:

- check the index how the field is indexed (might be not indexed at all)
- make sure you have a field that indexes the "no bedrooms" part of your custom field (separately) - I would assume you will need to create a computed field to achieve this
- create the facet and point it to the (computed) index field